# How can I increase the AMPs in a transformer less power supply

Tags: arduino, voltage, amplifier, esp8266, nodemcu

I am very new to electronics and trying to do something which I am not much aware of yet. I have a NodeMCU (based on esp8266) for which I need power supply of 5V and it required I guess more then 300mA for the properly working. I use to power it either by USB or mobile charger, which makes it working awesome so far.

But now I want to mount it to my own circuit so I can customise few things. So in order to create that power I have used a circuit diagram I found on YouTube.

[image]

The things is with this circuit diagram I can get the 5V power but the AMP is not what is needed, so my NodeMCU starts to heat up very quickly if I use this power supply and basically my NodeMCU looks damaged now.

So I just want to know few things :

- How can I increase the `mA` in this circuit?
- Is it reliable for 24x7 running for days or even months?
- Is there any formula to calculate the capacitor (red capacitor from circuit diagram) I need to use to make it work?

I try to attach instead of `470uF 25v` I replaced with `2.2uF 63v` (it was available with me so thought to use this for testing purpose) it increased the voltage value. But the `mA` or power stayed the same.

For basic reference, I have 230V AC power supply.

Any guidance will be helpful here!

Thank you! (in advance)

Comment: If your NodeMCU heats up it is not because you don't have enough current...there is some other problem. Please show a schematic of the actual circuit you built, along with a part number for the zener diode. Be sure to show actual resistor and capacitor values on your schematic.

Comment: What in the absolute [censored] do you need 300 amps for‽

Comment: Please just get a proper power supply. Capacitive dropper supplies such as these do not isolate your circuit from mains, leading to electrocution risks. Also, they are only practical for providing small currents.

Comment: @Hearth I want to have Mili Amps not Amps, sorry its my mistake.

Comment: What @marcelm said. This type of power supply is _dangerous_ and besides that you're using a zener diode as a shunt regulator, which is extremely inefficient and provides a poorly-regulated output, so your circuit might not be too happy either.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson sure I can understand, it can be because of any other reason. As I was trying to power the NodeMCU with multiple voltages. I have even tried powering up with 8V as I have read somewhere that I can support upto 9V so I tried with 8v. To create 8v I have used 5v and 3v zener diode in series. In terms of capacitor (red capacitor) I tried with 2 different capacitors `CBB22 684J 400V` and `CL21X 225K 450E`. I hope this will help.

Comment: @Hearth so what circuit should I use? Any reference link or diagram to understand?

Comment: @user3201500 Using a 9V battery with a 7805 is a common beginner's power supply. It's not a very good power supply and can't provide much current, but it's safe. If you need more current, a battery pack of six AAs gives you 9V with a higher current capacity. Four AAs gives you 6V, and a better linear regulator than the 7805 could give you regulated 5V from that, too, without wasting as much power.

Comment: @Hearth first of all thank you for the precautions and quick replies. I want to connect the circuit to my main switch board. Which is small and I want to run that 24x7 as my switch can be active or disable at anytime by anyone in my home. So battery won't be an option for me. I have to use 230AC to 5V DC supply so even behind the switch board as well i don't have to worry about replacing batteries.

Comment: @user3201500 When you're new to electronics, _please_ don't try to design anything that's going to go into your main switch board (by which I assume you mean your distribution unit or fuse box)

Comment: I am worried .... you are building a **`deadly circuit`**, but you do not seem to have the knowledge to do so, otherwise you would not say `increase the AMPs`, you would say `increase the current` .......... it is like someone that wants to turn up the heat and says `increase the degrees celsius`

Answer (score 3):

> I am very new to electronics and trying to do something which I am not much aware of yet.

It is a very bad idea to begin electronics working on mains circuits. You should purchase a 5 V power supply with adequate current rating for your project. Ensure that it has the relevant safety certification marks on it.

> I have a NodeMCU (based on esp8266) for which I need power supply of 5V and it required I guess more then 300amp for the properly working.

Your 300 amps requirement is most unlikely. Presumably you mean 300 mA.

> I use to power it either by USB or mobile charger, which makes it working awesome so far.

Stick with the awesome solution.

> But now I want to mount it to my own circuit so I can customise few things.

You need 5 V. There isn't anything to customise in this regard.

> So in order to create that power I have used a circuit diagram I found on YouTube.

Oh-oh!

> The things is with this circuit diagram I can get the 5 V power but the AMP is not what is needed, so my NodeMCU starts to heat up very quickly if I use this power supply and basically my NodeMCU looks damaged now.

It sounds like you gave it more than 5 V.

> How can I increase the AMP in this circuit?

By careful design for operation with specified minimum and maximum load.

> Is it reliable for 24x7 running for days or even months?

A well designed one might be.

> For basic reference, I have 230V AC power supply.

This is the scary part. That power supply circuit does not isolate your Node device from the mains. All parts of it must be considered live and if you connect a programmer or laptop to it that will be live too. This presents a serious shock hazard to anyone coming in contact with the circuit.

Proceeding with this PSU is not recommended for safety reasons.

Comment: And to the asker: if you absolutely must avoid using a commercial power supply, make your own _battery-powered_ one. With nice, easy to use alkaline batteries, not lithium ones.

Comment: I understand its a risk and I am taking all the precaution for it. I am not taking risk of my life, for a circuit :) So don't worry. I have a professional electrician with me.

Comment: If you have a *responsible* professional electrician with you, they should have you duct-taped to a chair by now!

Comment: You forgot to mention that if this was connected to a PC via a USB or serial port for any reason that USB is probably also fried.

Comment: I once saw a student connect a protoboard via a bunch of alligator clips into long naked wires that protruded at least 10cm above the board. There were at least 8 wires carrying 110 in this fashion. I did what any responsible professional electrical engineer would do, take 3 steps back and give a tongue lashing to his instructor.

Answer (score 2):

> For basic reference, I have 230V AC power supply.
>
> Any guidance will be helpful here!

OK. Basic guidance  - DON'T DO IT! STOP!

I know, you don't think that this is helpful. Trust me, if you keep this up, somebody may get hurt, and that somebody is very likely going to be you.

Until you have a great deal more experience, DO NOT do anything which involves sticking wires into wall sockets. Even if you use a wall plug and wires, the rest of your circuit is potentially deadly due to it being connected directly to the AC lines. So just don't do it.

> How can I increase the AMP in this circuit?

That's not the problem. Since you've apparently damaged your NodeMCU, lack of current is not the issue.

> Is it reliable for 24x7 running for days or even months?

If you do it right.

> Is there any formula to calculate the capacitor (red capacitor from
>   circuit diagram) I need to use to make it work?

The starting place would be formula for the impedance of a capacitor at a given frequency, but that is not the problem.

Instead, go on eBay and buy a cheap 5 volt supply.

Answer (score 0):

The way that professional product designers approach this problem is that they look at the vast multitude of good, cheap 5V regulated wall-warts that are on the market, and they *buy one*.  Or you buy 100,000 a year.  Whatever.  Unless you're selling millions of units, you just don't *make* these.

Comment: Or if you're trying to save every fraction of a penny that you can, which is where the asker's example gets used. I've seen it in cheap crap from ebay and aliexpress, but never in anything reputable.